# checkpassword-pam works locally, but not through qmail

Tags: linux, ubuntu, pam

I have [checkpassword-pam](https://sourceforge.net/projects/checkpasswd-pam/) 0.99, and when I run it locally, as in

```
echo -e 'testuser\0theuserspassword\0.' | 
    /usr/local/bin/checkpassword-pam -s smtp --debug --stdout /usr/bin/id 3<&0
```

everything works, and I get

```
Reading username and password
Username 'testuser'
Password read successfully
Initializing PAM library using service name 'smtp'
PAM library initialization succeeded
conversation(): msg[0], style PAM_PROMPT_ECHO_OFF, msg = "Password: "
Authentication passed
Account management succeeded
Setting PAM credentials succeeded
PAM session opened
PAM session closed
Terminating PAM library
Executing /usr/bin/id
uid=1001(testuser) gid=1001(testuser) groups=1001(testuser)
```

(If I don't do `--stdout` it logs to auth.log, and still succeeds)

When invoked via qmail it looks like I somehow have a modified library load path, because PAM's dlopen()s don't work:

```
Dec 28 21:19:43 standby smtp[18229]: Reading username and password
Dec 28 21:19:43 standby smtp[18229]: Username 'testuser'
Dec 28 21:19:43 standby smtp[18229]: Password read successfully
Dec 28 21:19:43 standby smtp[18229]: Initializing PAM library using service name 'smtp'
Dec 28 21:19:43 standby smtp[18229]: PAM unable to dlopen(pam_systemd.so): /lib/security/pam_systemd.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Dec 28 21:19:43 standby smtp[18229]: PAM adding faulty module: pam_systemd.so
Dec 28 21:19:43 standby smtp[18229]: PAM library initialization succeeded
Dec 28 21:19:43 standby smtp[18229]: conversation(): msg[0], style PAM_PROMPT_ECHO_OFF, msg = "Password: "
Dec 28 21:19:43 standby smtp[18229]: pam_unix(smtp:auth): check pass; user unknown
Dec 28 21:19:43 standby smtp[18229]: pam_unix(smtp:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=64011 euid=0 tty= ruser= rhost=71.217.92.189
Dec 28 21:19:45 standby smtp[18229]: Authentication failed: Authentication failure
Dec 28 21:19:45 standby smtp[18229]: Exiting with status 1
```

Since the correct path for `pam_systemd.so` is `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/security/pam_systemd.so`.

Nothing in the environment block for the qmail-invoked `checkpassword-pam` looks out of place (per a modification to print everything from the `environ` global):

```
Dec 28 21:19:43 standby smtp[18229]: Env: PATH=/command:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/X11R6/bin:/snap/bin
Dec 28 21:19:43 standby smtp[18229]: Env: PWD=/var/qmail/supervise/qmail-smtpd
Dec 28 21:19:43 standby smtp[18229]: Env: SHLVL=0
Dec 28 21:19:43 standby smtp[18229]: Env: XDG_DATA_DIRS=/usr/local/share:/usr/share:/var/lib/snapd/desktop
Dec 28 21:19:43 standby smtp[18229]: Env: PROTO=TCP
Dec 28 21:19:43 standby smtp[18229]: Env: TCPLOCALIP=an.ip.v4.address
Dec 28 21:19:43 standby smtp[18229]: Env: TCPLOCALPORT=25
Dec 28 21:19:43 standby smtp[18229]: Env: TCPLOCALHOST=fqdn
Dec 28 21:19:43 standby smtp[18229]: Env: TCPREMOTEIP=another.ip.v4.address
Dec 28 21:19:43 standby smtp[18229]: Env: TCPREMOTEPORT=44994
Dec 28 21:19:43 standby smtp[18229]: Env: TCPREMOTEHOST=anotherfqdn
```

The presence of the `TCPREMOTEIP` environment variable does make checkpassword-pam set the RHOST value to the PAM session, but I've also tried with that section commented out.

Ubuntu 16.04 x64 from Digital Ocean
+ daemontools, ucspi-tcp, gcc, libpam0g-dev, libssl-dev, qmail-uids-gids

Custom built qmail, custom built checkpassword-pam.

```
# file /var/qmail/bin/qmail-smtpd `which tcpserver` `which checkpassword-pam`
/var/qmail/bin/qmail-smtpd:       ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, for GNU/Linux 2.6.32, BuildID[sha1]=e858c3d33bb8fea26d7618e3ce63c37dc7c0557d, stripped
/usr/bin/tcpserver:               ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, for GNU/Linux 2.6.15, BuildID[sha1]=1e727ea57ca4de886e56b6783de7df0190a2ad26, stripped
/usr/local/bin/checkpassword-pam: setuid ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, for GNU/Linux 2.6.32, BuildID[sha1]=8b6e3fffb52cab99526653078e0fd018b5e97a77, not stripped
```

With nothing in the environment block looking out of place I can't really figure out what's going on.  I know I had this working on an Ubuntu server in the past, but I recall it being a frustrating process of failure followed by it working without me understanding why.  And now I can't reproduce the success path.

**Edit**: `ldd` output, as requested:

New machine (doesn't work):

```
$ ldd /usr/local/bin/checkpassword-pam
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffc6daf4000)
    libpam.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpam.so.0 (0x00007fa12f54f000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fa12f185000)
    libaudit.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libaudit.so.1 (0x00007fa12ef5e000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007fa12ed5a000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fa12f75d000)
```

A different Ubuntu machine where it seems to be working:

```
$ ldd /usr/local/bin/checkpassword-pam
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffd437ab000)
    libpam.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpam.so.0 (0x00007ff6cfe89000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007ff6cfab9000)
    libaudit.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libaudit.so.1 (0x00007ff6cf891000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007ff6cf689000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007ff6d0099000)
```

Package info:

```
$ dpkg -l | grep libpam
ii  libpam-modules:amd64             1.1.8-3.2ubuntu2                             amd64        Pluggable Authentication Modules for PAM
ii  libpam-modules-bin               1.1.8-3.2ubuntu2                             amd64        Pluggable Authentication Modules for PAM - helper binaries
ii  libpam-runtime                   1.1.8-3.2ubuntu2                             all          Runtime support for the PAM library
ii  libpam-systemd:amd64             229-4ubuntu21                                amd64        system and service manager - PAM module
ii  libpam0g:amd64                   1.1.8-3.2ubuntu2                             amd64        Pluggable Authentication Modules library
ii  libpam0g-dev:amd64               1.1.8-3.2ubuntu2                             amd64        Development files for PAM

$ dpkg -l | grep systemd
ii  libpam-systemd:amd64             229-4ubuntu21                                amd64        system and service manager - PAM module
ii  libsystemd0:amd64                229-4ubuntu21                                amd64        systemd utility library
ii  python3-systemd                  231-2build1                                  amd64        Python 3 bindings for systemd
ii  systemd                          229-4ubuntu21                                amd64        system and service manager
ii  systemd-sysv                     229-4ubuntu21                                amd64        system and service manager - SysV links

$ dpkg -S /lib/security/pam_systemd.so
dpkg-query: no path found matching pattern /lib/security/pam_systemd.so

$ ls -ld /lib/security/pam_systemd.so
ls: cannot access '/lib/security/pam_systemd.so': No such file or directory

$ locate pam_systemd.so
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/security/pam_systemd.so

$ dpkg -S `locate pam_systemd.so`
libpam-systemd:amd64: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/security/pam_systemd.so
```

Identical package results between the erroring and succeeding machines.

Comment: Please, can you provide the output of `ldd /usr/local/bin/checkpassword-pam` given right after a succesfull CLI-based authentication (the first one you mentioned)? I think you're facing with some `systemd`-related PATH problems

Comment: Please,  provide also : `dpkg -l | grep libpam` and `dpkg -l | grep systemd` and `dpkg -S /lib/security/pam_systemd.so` and... just as an excess of verification: `ls -ld /lib/security/pam_systemd.so`

Comment: Please, cut-and-paste my commands, as I'm interested in their output (and not only to INSTALLED packages)

Comment: @DamianoVerzulli Updated the output.  There's no /lib/security directory at all (either machine).

Comment: As Debian developed the multilib scheme to handle all cases of architectures with multiple sets of libraries, `[/usr]/lib/*` paths were changed to `[/usr]/lib/<architecture name>/*`. This scheme can cover not only 32/64-bit hardware like x86_64 or SPARC hardware, but also all sorts of weird ARM implementations.

Answer (score 0):

check

```
debconf-show libpam-runtime
```

is pam using systemd?

yes - check

```
/etc/pam.d/common-session
```

No?
remove systemd

```
pam-auth-update --package --remove systemd
```

Comment: `libpam-runtime/profiles: unix, systemd` / `session optional        pam_systemd.so`. Not sure how this helps identify why the dload is failing sometimes, but not others.  (And, more importantly, why the pam_unix module reports "user unknown")

Comment: The path is incorrect probably from an incomplete upgrade or such - it should be safe to remove or certainly to reinstall libpam-systemd

Comment: No upgrades were involved.  I made a new VM on Digital Ocean, picked the Ubuntu 16.04 x64 base image, and away I went into "everything, except this one thing, works".

Comment: but the path /lib/security is the old path. can you print the contents of /lib/lsb/init-functions.d/40-systemd

Comment: olso - this should be non destructive and worth investigating `sudo apt-get install --reinstall libpam-systemd`

Comment: Reinstalled, no joy.  Reinstalled libpam0g, no joy.  Same errors.

Comment: it still trys to load the library from the wrong location? - man, just McGeever it and make a link or copy to the location it thinks it should be

Comment: >>pam_unix module reports "user unknown" 

IIRC you’d get the error if it’s a non-root process. Does qmail run as root?

Comment: @Najmuddin checkpassword-pam is setuid 0 (and that was verified by using it as another unprivileged user)